# php xml cms not displaying output

Tags: php, content-management-system, simplexml

Basically im developing a video system for my youtube videos heres how i wanted it to work

mysite.com/video.php?id=1

```
<?php
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $sxl = simplexml_load_file("videos.xml");

 $vid =  $sxl->videos->video;
 $video = $vid[$id];
 echo   $video->title;
 ?>
```

And my videos.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <data>
 <videos>
 <video id="1">
 <title>Test</title>
 </video>
 </videos>
 </data>
```

When it loads the page it displays nothing, please help there will be multiple videos

Comment: What are you trying to print... `Test`?

Comment: Just the title of the video(For now) and im not using sql

Comment: You need to loop through the video element instead of $video = $vid[$id];

Comment: How do i do that? Im not using foreach to display multiple items im using something similar to PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `xPath` to select the desired node:

```
$video = $sxl->xpath("//video[@id='$id']")[0]; // req PHP >= 5.4
echo $video->title;
```

If you want to get the title only:

```
$title = $sxl->xpath("//video[@id='$id']/title")[0]; // req PHP >= 5.4
echo $title;
```

If you have PHP < 5.4:

```
$video = $sxl->xpath("//video[@id='$id']");
echo $video[0]->title;
```

Comment: Thank you i wish i though of this

Comment: @user2985446 Next time, you will think of this :-) Please consider to accept my answer by clicking the tick-mark on the left.